# Kile remove horizontal scrolling

Tags: wrap, kile, ide

I always love kile. But I hate the problem that a long paragraph in kile goes beyond the screen and results in horizontal scrolling. I know this should a trivial problem and easily solved using some sort of wrapping. However, I am lost in so many settings and stackexchange Q&A. I hope I could explain my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am so frustrated because I could not find a working answer to this simple question which everyone should face in Kile. Sometimes I feel the humankind is not going forward to a simple and easy to understand world!

**Edit:** I figured it out. Kile has a problem (possibly a bug) that the word wrapping actually works after some time you pressed the `ok` button. At least for me this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In KILE, go to `Settings --> Configure Kile --> Editor --> Appearance` tab. Here you will find options on `Word Wrap`, which you can use. Another option is to wrap text after `n` characters. This option can be set from`Settings --> Configure Kile --> Editor --> Editing` tab.